# How can I send vm info over snmp?

Tags: virtual-machines, snmp, libvirt, mib

I have a script I'm using on Fedora 34 to gather basic info about VMs running on a machine such as CPU cores, memory, drive path & size, and disk IO. How can I send this information over snmp using snmpwalk? I'm aware of of libvirt-snmp but it doesn't send all of the data that I need. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which SNMP OIDs are missing? Could you show a snmwalk output for libvirt-snmap mib?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici The libvirt-snmp output is practically everything I need except disk I/O and drive path. I've been trying to find ways to include those with libvirt-snmp but have been stuck.

Comment: I can't find any SNMP OID in [LIBVIRT-MIB.txt](https://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt-snmp.git;a=blob;f=src/LIBVIRT-MIB.txt;hb=1ad3cf35db0ea437d775dc988ff197575ae349bb) defining disk IO and guest disk info, try adding `snmpwalk` output of OID `1.3.6.1.4.1.36957`.